# Reference the Current State of a DataFrame during Method Chaining

Tags: python, pandas, method-chaining

I often find I can map a step in a process to a sequence of vectrorized methods on a Series or DataFrame.

example

```
step1 = df.a_column.reindex(target.index)
result = step1.where(step1 > 0, 1)
```

But what I really want is this on one line

```
result = df.a_column.reindex(target.index).where( ? >0, 1)
```

How can you reference what was step1 in the first example?

I am using pandas 12 . I think in 13, the query method will assume the context of the current object, but I don't know if that returns the same shape as the source.

Comment: Take pity on the people who maintain your code after you: don't use long lines of code.  Instead, use meaningful variable names for intermediate results.

Comment: The chain does not have to be that long for the ability to reference an intermediate result to be useful.

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible ATM. I suppose the query machinery could be used in something like ``[sequence of operations yielding a frame].where("A>0",1)``; we'd have to process the condition w.r.t. the input to the where in this case. Might be useful for ``where`` (and in theory indexing functions); I created an issue, feel free to comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5501

Answer (score 2):

This video ([effective pandas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zgbUk90aQ6A)) changed my world of pandas. Your solution is at minute 49:10.

You can capture a dataframe's state mid-chain by piping in a helper function that defines a new variable name into the global namespace:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


def catchstate(df, var_name: str) -> 'pd.DataFrame':
    """
    Helper function that captures intermediate Dataframes mid-chain.
    In the global namespace, make a new variable called var_name and set it to dataframe
    """
    globals()[var_name] = df
    return df


# LOAD TESTDATA
df = sns.load_dataset("fmri")

df = (df
      .rename(columns={"timepoint": "TIMEPOINT"})
      .pipe(catchstate, var_name="DF2")
      .where(df["timepoint"] > 15, "foo")
      .assign(timepoint_copy = DF2["TIMEPOINT"])
      )

print(df.head(5))
```

```
  subject TIMEPOINT event    region signal  timepoint_copy
0     s13        18  stim  parietal -0.018              18
1     foo       foo   foo       foo    foo              14
2     s12        18  stim  parietal -0.081              18
3     s11        18  stim  parietal -0.046              18
4     s10        18  stim  parietal -0.038              18
```